# Finding the sub string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string like

```
Strig foo = "PrinciplexbxbxbxbxbxbTeachershshshshshhsClassdhdhdhhdhdhdList[something to be extracted]jdjdjdj"
```

I want output to be "something to be extracted" where regex of string is `Principle*Teacher*Class*List[*]*.`

After this make a new string

```
 Strig foo = "PrinciplexbxbxbxbxbxbTeachershshshshshhsClassdhdhdhhdhdhdList[something new]jdjdjdj"
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What did you try? You already mentioned regex (although the string you posted is not a suitable regex), so what's the problem?

Comment: `*` isn't a wildcard in regex ; it's a quantifier : it applies to the previous token to describe it can happen any number of times (including 0). For the generic wildcard you want `.*`, which is any character any number of times.

Comment: Regex playground: http://regex101.com

Comment: @arminb and all . thanks for regex101 link. This would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

If your `String` is always in the same format and contains the words `Principle`, `Teachers` and `Class` followed by `[some text]`, then this is **[the Regex](https://regex101.com/r/tTXDpP/1)** you need :

```
Principle\\w*Teachers\\w*Class\\w*\\[([\\s\\w]+)\\]\\w*
```

The matching group in `\\[([\\s\\w]+)\\]` will match the string you need.

Your code would be like this:

```
final String regex = "Principle\\w*Teachers\\w*Class\\w*\\[([\\s\\w]+)\\]\\w*";
final String string = "Strig foo = \"PrinciplexbxbxbxbxbxbTeachershshshshshhsClassdhdhdhhdhdhdList[something to be extracted]jdjdjdj\"\n";

string.replaceAll(regex, "something new");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `something to be extracted` then you can extract every thing between the two brackets `\[(.*?)\]`, you can use Pattern like this :

```
String foo = ...;
String regex = "\\[(.*)\\]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(foo);

if (matcher.find()) {                                                
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

---

If you want to replace it you can use replaceAll with the same regex :

```
foo = foo.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "[something new]");
```

## regex demo